# Pagination ChangeNotifierProvider con StreamBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, firestore

Tengo un StreamBuilder que muestra un listado de rutinas que se suben a Firebase, se espera que este listado sea grande pero todas se deben cargar para acceder a ellas con un buscador de text, estoy usando un ChangeNotifierProvider para no mostrar todo el listado y saturar la app, sin embargo en el caso de que actualice desde Firebase una rutina, no se ve actualizado en el ChangeNotifierProvider.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
RegistrosProvider registros = RegistrosProvider(
  widget.list,
  widget.pag,
);

return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
  },
  child: [ChangeNotifierProvider][1]<RegistrosProvider>(
    create: (context) => registros,
    child:
        Consumer<RegistrosProvider>(builder: (context, usersProvider, _) {
      return ListViewWidget(
        usersProvider,
        widget.widgetList,
        widget.busqueda,
      );
    }),
  ),
);
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no crees objetos dentro del método `build`

Comment: estaba haciendo pruebas, pero el detalle persiste